# create-react-app yields 'the request of a dependency is an expression' in express/lib/view.js

Tags: reactjs, feathersjs, create-react-app

I'm trying to get a jump start with React and like the simplicity of the create-react-app tool created by Facebook and described here:

https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/07/22/create-apps-with-no-configuration.html

Can anybody tell me what is wrong here?

I'm trying to combine it with FeatherJS and add this dependency to package.json:

```
"feathers": "^2.0.0"
```

and this to App.js:

```
import feathers from 'feathers';
```

Now my web app will not load and I get this error in the console:

```
    Compiled with warnings.

    Warning in ./src/App.js

    /Users/nikolaschou/Dev/newbanking/payment-window/src/App.js
    4:8  warning  'feathers' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

    ✖ 1 problem (0 errors, 1 warning)


    Warning in ./~/express/lib/view.js
    Critical dependencies:
    78:29-56 the request of a dependency is an expression
    @ ./~/express/lib/view.js 78:29-56

    You may use special comments to disable some warnings.
    Use // eslint-disable-next-line to ignore the next line.
    Use /* eslint-disable */ to ignore all warnings in a file.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by [its documentation](https://docs.feathersjs.com/), `feathers` ifself is **the server** and runs on Node.

On the other hand, a React app is a **client-side application** and runs in the browser.

You can't import `feathers` into a browser app because it is a library intended only for the server.

> *Note: Technically React apps can run on the server too but Create React App doesn't currently support server rendering. It also comes with many pitfalls so I recommend holding off using it until you are comfortable with React itself.*

Normally, with Create React App, you are expected to run your API server (which may use Feathers) separately as a Node (or any other) app. The React client would access it via AJAX or other network APIs.

Your Node app would use `feathers` for the server, and React app would use [`feathers/client`](https://docs.feathersjs.com/clients/feathers.html) to communicate with it.

To read about setting up a Node and a client-side React app to talk to each other, check out [this tutorial](https://www.fullstackreact.com/articles/using-create-react-app-with-a-server/) and its [demo](https://github.com/fullstackreact/food-lookup-demo).

Comment: Yes of course, good answer. Feathers is both on the client and on the server side but in this case I should have imported the feathers client. I should have seen this myself as the error comes in the express library which is clearly server side.

Comment: We will update the React tutorial to use the new create-react-app tool for the next release. Also, the usage with client side module loaders is documented at https://docs.feathersjs.com/clients/feathers.html#usage-in-nodejs-and-client-module-loaders